# How to decorate loader methods to use with loading indicator components? (in Vue)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, decorator

To reuse load progress indicating, I've created a component with a slot and a enum prop like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="loaded-listing">
        <div class="loaded-listing__loading-placeholder" v-if="isLoading">
            <some-third-party-indicator ... />
        </div>
        <slot v-else />
        <!-- the Failed status is not displayed yet -->
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    export enum loadStatusEnum {
        Loading,
        Loaded,
        Failed
    }

    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
    import { SomeThirdPartyIndicator } from 'some-third-party-indicator'

    @Component({
        props: ['loadStatus'],
        components: { SomeThirdPartyIndicator },
    })
    export default class LoadedListing extends Vue {
        @Prop() readonly loadStatus!: loadStatusEnum;
        get isLoading (): boolean {
            return this.loadStatus == loadStatusEnum.Loading
        }
    }

</script>
```

For each loading in a view/component, I use it like this:

```
import LoadedListing, { loadStatusEnum } from '../components/LoadedListing.vue'

export default class SomePage extends Vue {
    ...
    someStuffLoadStatus: loadStatusEnum = loadStatusEnum.Loading; // 1
    loadSomeStuff (): void {
        this.someStuffLoadStatus = loadStatusEnum.Loading; // 2
        this.$store.dispatch('someModule/loadSomeStuff', ...) // some model updating in a callback
            .then(() => this.someStuffLoadStatus = loadStatusEnum.Loaded) // 3
            .catch(() => this.someStuffLoadStatus = loadStatusEnum.Failed) // 4
    }
    ...
}
```

and in template:

```
<LoadedListing class="some-stuff-list" :load-status="someStuffLoadStatus">
    <div class="some-stuff-list__top-panel"> ... </div>
    <VueSimplebar class="some-stuff-list__body" ...> ... </VueSimplebar>
</LoadedListing>
```

What I don't like about this approach is:

- I write lines 1-4 for each loader
- I create the `someStuffLoadStatus` property inside the parent component and pass it as a prop to the component but it has nothing to do with the main model, it only reflects the load status used by the component

it seems that it would be more adequate to just ~decorate the loader and somehow connect it with a certain component instance (using `ref`?) but I'm not sure how can I implement this. Could you propose an approach to such decorating/connecting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how decorating would work with Typescript/Vue, but in one of my projects I simply used a mixin to provide such feature.

The following solution is untested but gives you a general idea on how to use this mixin for keeping track of loading states:

```js
// loading_mixin.js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loader: {
                // This object will contain various keys you pass to
                // the `wrap()` function `type` parameter.
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        /**
         * @param {Promise} promise
         * @param {String} type
         * @returns {Promise}
         */
        wrap(promise, type) {
            let loaded = this.loader[type] ? this.loader[type].loaded : false;
            this.$set(this.loader, type, {loading: true, loaded: loaded});
            return promise.then((data) => {
                this.$set(this.loader, type, {loading: false, loaded: true});
                return data;
            }).catch((err) => {
                this.$set(this.loader, type, {loading: false, loaded: false});
                throw err;
            });
        },
    }
}
```

Usage (`YourComponent.vue`):

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <loading-component :loader="loader.load_data" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import loadingMixin from '...';
    export default {
        mixin: [loadingMixin],
        methods: {
            load() {
                this.wrap(this.loadMyData(1, 2), 'load_data').then((data) => {
                    // Handle success.
                }).catch((err) => {
                    // Handle err.
                })
            },
            loadMyData(a, b) {
                return Promise.resolve(a + b);
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: thanks, "single loader per component" is not nice in my case (although I can create additional components, it is not needed for any other reason), but I'll take a look at mixins and search a bit more

Comment: yes I thought so, i've yet to see an elegant solution, but I think you can change the `wrap()` function to take an additional parameter like an identifier, and then use that identifier to set a key in the `loading` property, which now becomes an object (key = identifier, value = true/false)

Comment: i've rewritten the answer, maybe this will help you